# Most efficient way to calculate the average of a function between pairs for each element in Python?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization, numpy-ndarray

**Problem:**

- I have M objects sampled at different frames and I want to calculate the distance between pairs at each frame. I store the distances as a multidimensional array `xij` with three axis, where the element `xij[t,i,j]` corresponds to the distance between the objects `i` and `j` at time `t`. For example, we could have:

  ```py
  N  = 10**5
  M = 10
  xij = np.random.uniform(0, 10, N).reshape(int(N/M**2), M, M)
  ```
- Now I want to calculate **for each element the average distance to other pairs** (that is, *excluding pairs between the same objects* `xij[t,i,i]`). The way I implemented this was first changing the values of these indices to NaN and then using `np.nanmean()`:

  ```py
  xij[...,np.arange(M), np.arange(M)] = np.nan
  mean = np.nanmean(xij, axis = -1)
  ```
- However, changing all these values to `np.nan` becomes a bottleneck in my program and it seems to me that maybe is not necessary. **Is there a faster alternative?** I see there is an argument `where` in `np.mean` to choose the elements to include in the calculation as a boolen array. I wonder if you could create this array more efficiently than using the `Nan` trick I implemented. Or alternatively, maybe using masked arrays? Although I am not familiar with them.

Comment: Which kind of distance are you calculating? The euclidean distance will be 0 for pairs of the same object, which simplifies a possible solution a bit. Another possibility to get huge speedups is to do everything at once (using Numba or Cython).

Comment: What kind of distance is it and what how many dimensions does this problem have. Is it just 2D or 3D? If you are looking for huge speedups there might be possibilities to do all at once.

Comment: @max9111 Actually it has a shape of (61, 3, 10000, 40, 40) and I want to do the pairs between the last two indices (the other axis are kind of parameters). It is just a function similar as a distance between the pairs, symmetrical for the last two indices and zero for the same indices.

Comment: With whole-array methods, trying to exclude certain pairs (such as self ones whose distance will be 0), may be more expensive.  If you are writing compiled code with custom iteration skipping certain pairs may save time, but `numpy` is fastest when using the compiled building blocks that it provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sum, subtract the diagonal, and divide by M-1:

```
meanDistance = (np.sum(xij, axis = -1) - np.diagonal(xij, axis1=-2, axis2=-1))  / (M - 1)
```

Demo results:

```
(sum-diag) / (M-1):
  time in seconds: 0.03786587715148926
  t=0 first three means: [5.42617836 5.03198446 5.67675881]

nanmean:
  time in seconds: 0.18410110473632812
  t=0 first three means: [5.42617836 5.03198446 5.67675881]
```

Demo code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVAxbsMwDNz1Cm6RDNmxk6FAAG9d7Q8EGYRYSVRUlCApQPJ6l7LdNPBeQAN1PPKO55/p5nA/jsZ6FxLg3fonqAjo2SU4C8lYDUsz14z1AC00dVF8sG6q2MN8UYG@CgoHZ6s7mosLlteSuhJ6UQUdb8prbjDxftsVxU5I6OgJxnzI6IbHuy0Ho64CtsC7shGHjWCpps1ZlwtmtcJPE5PCsyaUkyDNcFKXoB4mEkZTUGYneZFD9f3XbdpyN1e7lmgCJhliN@LXAizXIkR9djjEw0Yu4sRL9TuxreFiQqRQbkFryN4m@rvJYy0P@9PrxNc4Ksy09X1k9VhVlST7ipK8at5RSu@/0xwzza/DmNEMrvP47@PG8Qc)):

```
import numpy as np
from time import time

N  = 10**7
M = 10
xij = np.random.uniform(0, 10, N).reshape(int(N/M**2), M, M)

print('(sum-diag) / (M-1):')
t0 = time()
meanDistance = (np.sum(xij, axis = -1) - np.diagonal(xij, axis1=-2, axis2=-1))  / (M - 1)
print('  time in seconds:', time() - t0)
print('  t=0 first three means:', meanDistance[0,:3])

print()
print('nanmean:')
t0 = time()
xij[...,np.arange(M), np.arange(M)] = np.nan
meanDistance = np.nanmean(xij, axis = -1)
print('  time in seconds:', time() - t0)
print('  t=0 first three means:', meanDistance[0,:3])
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, because it is not only on calculating the average of distances between pairs, but doing the distance calculation and averaging all at once.

**Assumptions**

- Euclidean distance between pairs
- The distance calculation is based on one array, diagonal elements are zero
- `points` is an array with axis corresponding to `(time, element, coordinate of the position)`

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit(fastmath=True,inline="never")
def mean_dist_inner(points,res):
    div=1/(points.shape[0]-1)

    for i in range(points.shape[0]):
        acc=0
        for j in range(points.shape[0]):
            dist=0
            for k in range(points.shape[1]):
                dist+=(points[i,k]-points[j,k])**2
            acc+=np.sqrt(dist)
        res[i]=acc*div
    return

@nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True,cache=True)
def mean_dist_time(points):

    res=np.empty((points.shape[0],points.shape[1]),dtype=np.float64)

    for t in nb.prange(points.shape[0]):
        mean_dist_inner(points[t],res[t])
    return res
```

**Timing**

```
points=np.random.rand(10000,40,40)
%timeit mean_dist_time(points)
#40.1 ms ± 9.04 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: To compare with the other answer, `%timeit mean_dist_time(points)` takes me **244 ms** ± 23.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each); while doing `%timeit xij = np.linalg.norm(points[:,:,None,:] - points[:,None,:,:], axis = -1)` takes **4.59 s** ± 633 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)  and then `%timeit (np.sum(xij, axis = -1) - np.diagonal(xij, axis1=-2, axis2=-1))  / (40 - 1)` takes **15.6 ms** ± 299 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each). So in total this answer appears to be faster (also both methods give the same results).

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I wrongly thoughted a distance needed to be calculated first.
This seems a reshape exercise together with [numpy.triu_indices](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html). If the distance `x[i,j] != x[j,i]` you need a combination with `triu_indices` & `tril_indices`.

I assume `x[i,j] = x[j,i]`, than:

```
import numpy as np

N = 10000
xij = np.random.uniform(0, 10, (N,N))
```

```
np.mean( xij[ np.tril_indices(N, k=1) ] )
```

---

If there is a dimension time, like

```
N  = 10**5
M = 10
xij = np.random.uniform(0, 10, N).reshape(int(N/M**2), M, M)
```

You could

```
N_dim = xij.shape[-1]

[ np.mean( xij[t,:][np.tril_indices(N_dim, k=1)] ) for t in range(xij.shape[0]) ]
```

To get a list of means, or the overal mean with

```
N_dim = xij.shape[-1]

np.mean( [ np.mean( xij[t,:][np.tril_indices(N_dim, k=1)] ) for t in range(xij.shape[0]) ] )
```

Comment: I wrongly assumed you need to calculate the pdist first, but seems that is the step that already happened, and now you want a average

Comment: please add that to the question

Comment: Mm I think this gives the average distance for all pairs and for all elements? Maybe it was not too clear, but what I asked was for each element the average distance to all the other pairs excluding itself.

Comment: If I understand, that would be a exercise of column wise means, excluding the diagonal? You can remove diagonal for A with A[~np.eye(A.shape[0],dtype=bool)].reshape(A.shape[0],-1)